# Unable to login to Sharepoint when using FQDN

Tags: 2013, authentication

I have Sharepoint 2013 installed in a single server configuration, with SQL Express Server installed on the same server.  I dont have Active Directory in my environment, so I'm using the local administrator account for authentication.

I'm accessing the site locally on the server.  When I use the FQDN (e.g. http://server1.mysite.com) I get an authentication prompt, and it fails.  When I use just the server name (eg. http://server1) I'm able to authenticate and the site displays.

Reading some other answers on this site, there seems to be talk about disabling the loopback check and a reference to this article (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/896861).  I did that, but it had no effect.

Also, the FQDN is properly configured in Control Panel - System. The full computer name shows correctly under full computer name.

Comment: Have you added your URL to the hosts file? It's located at C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: I'm able to get the authentication prompt when I use the FQDN.  So that tells me that I'm getting to the site.  The problem is, the same authentication that I use for the shortname site doesnt work for the FQDN site, even though they are the same thing

Comment: Loopback-Check is still the most obvious reason for this problem. Could you please add the detailled steps you configured to disable the check? Maybe there's an error in your RegKeys.